# Node.js - Could this miss some errors?

Tags: node.js

I'm reading Node.js in Action.  There is an example for a simple static file server, as follows:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    var url = parse(req.url);
    var path = join(root, url.pathname);

    var stream = fs.createReadStream(path);

    stream.pipe(res);
    stream.on('error', function(err) {
        res.statusCode=500;
        res.end('Internal Server Error');
    });
});
```

My question is, what happens if the stream.pipe() call hits an error BEFORE the 'error' handler is added to the stream?  Could it "miss" this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write `stream.pipe(res)`, it doesn't mean that streaming will start right at that line, it will just be scheduled to run once the code in the request handler is done (Node runs code in a single thread, so it can do only one thing at a time).

After the request handler is done, control is yielded back to the internal Node event loop, which will check to see if there is any I/O to be performed, like handling your stream. At that time, the `error` handler is already in place to handle any errors.

Comment: Thanks!  Node's bending my brain a bit, but I think that's a good thing. :-)

Comment: @loneboat yes it is! :)